# ViewPager not refreshing

Tags: android

I am using view pager in my android app to show images which automatically scroll after a particular time.

In my OnCreate I have defined the pager like this:

```
    List<String> urls;
    urls= new ArrayList<>();
    urls.add("http://<myserver>/adrotatecustom1.png");
    urls.add("http://<myserver>/adrotatecustom2.jpg");
    urls.add("http://<myserver>/adrotatecustom3.jpg");
    urls.add("http://<myserver>/adrotatecustom4.jpg");
    mImageViewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), urls));
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabDots);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mImageViewPager, true);
    autoSlider(mImageViewPager);
```

Autoslider method:

```
  public void autoSlider(final ViewPager viewPager) 
     {
       final Handler handler = new Handler();
       final Runnable rr = new Runnable() 
       {
        public void run() 
        {
            int i=0;
            int pos = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
            if(pos >= i && pos != mImages.length - 1){
                i = pos;
                i++;
            }
            else if(pos < (i-1)){
                i = pos;
                i++;
            }
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(i, true);
            i++;
            if (i >= mImages.length)
                i = 0;
                autoSlider(viewPager);

        }};
      handler.postDelayed(rr, 15000);
    }
```

Adapter for View Pager:

```
    public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context c;
    private List<String> _imagePaths;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context c, List<String> imagePaths) {
        this._imagePaths = imagePaths;
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this._imagePaths.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == (object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container,final int position) {
        ImageView imgDisplay;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) c
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_viewpagerlayout, container,
                false);

        imgDisplay = (ImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgViewpager);

        Picasso.with(c).load(_imagePaths.get(position)).into(imgDisplay);
        (container).addView(viewLayout);

        return viewLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        (container).removeView((LinearLayout) object);

    }
}
```

The problem is it working fine initially, if i change the image in server(different image with the same name), it is still referring to the old image, but i am not having the old image anywhere in the server. Can anyone help me what i am missing here.

Comment: Picasso Image loader library is caching your images since they are from the same url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if i change the image in server(different image with the same name), it is still referring to the old image

you need to clear cache of `Picasso`  use this **`.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)`**  and **`.networkpolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)`** to clear cache of `Picasso`

**CODE**

```
Picasso.with(c)
       .load(_imagePaths.get(position))
       .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
       .networkpolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
       .into(imgDisplay);
```

Answer (score 0):

use glide library for image loading :

```
 Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(_imagePaths.get(position)).
                diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT).
                placeholder(R.color.off_white).into(holder.imgImage);
```

in **build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Comment: **FYI** the latest version is **`compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'`**

Comment: ans also you missed the `Context` in glide check your ans mistake while posting ans

Answer (score 0):

> if i change the image in server(different image with the same name), it is still referring to the old image
>
> `ViewPager` not refreshing in android

**Don't use same name with different image** because when images are load at first time via `Picasso` Lib it will store in `CASH` memory and if from server side you will change image with old same name `Picasso` will predict it is a same image and display or load a **old image** not new one

**So my suggestion is: While updating images from your server you should have to store updated image name not same as previous.**

if you still want to use same name you can use **`.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)`** it will remove all `CACHE` memory form your application used by `Picasso`

**Example**

```
Picasso.with(context)
       .load(listView.get(position))
       .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
       .networkpolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
       .into(imageView);
```

> For more information **[official DOC](http://square.github.io/picasso/)** and **[memory-cache-Piccaso](https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/) MemoryPolicy class**

Answer (score 0):

its displaying old images because the URL is same while loading images and the library like `Picaso/Glide` is load image from cashe first. so if you want to load newly uploaded image then append `timestamp` in your `URL` and ImageLoading library autmaticaly load new image.

e.g. `url="http://abc.co/img.jpg?2017-12-31 11:12:13";`

in your case update your all `imagepaths`

Comment: will give this a try and let u know

Answer (score 0):

I used Glide for image loading and used  `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)`

Here is my method:

```
 @Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imgDisplay;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_image, container,
            false);
    imgDisplay = viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);

    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(_imagePaths.get(position));

    Glide.with(context).load(storageReference)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.avator)
            .error(R.drawable.avator)
            .into(imgDisplay);


    (container).addView(viewLayout);
    return viewLayout;
}
```